Why can I see many traffic forwarding on my machine
I'm working in a LAN, which is a cloud product. I have many Linux machines in this LAN. I deployed my whole web-service backend in this LAN.
Today, I executed tcpdump -i eth0 -nne -p on a machine, whose local IP is 172.16.0.11. To my surprise, I found many traffic forwarding records:
16:07:14.639206 fa:31:3f:2a:30:b7 > fa:31:3f:ba:7b:be, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1366: 172.16.0.227.9029 > 172.16.0.72.36726: Flags [P.], seq 2796:4096, ack 1, win 9677, options [nop,nop,TS val 483833918 ecr 1703882345], length 1300
16:07:14.639241 fa:31:3f:2a:30:b7 > fa:31:3f:ba:7b:be, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 2862: 172.16.0.227.9029 > 172.16.0.72.36726: Flags [.], seq 4096:6892, ack 1, win 9677, options [nop,nop,TS val 483833918 ecr 1703882345], length 2796
16:07:14.639267 fa:31:3f:2a:30:b7 > fa:31:3f:ba:7b:be, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1366: 172.16.0.227.9029 > 172.16.0.72.36726: Flags [P.], seq 6892:8192, ack 1, win 9677, options [nop,nop,TS val 483833918 ecr 1703882345], length 1300
16:07:14.639302 fa:31:3f:2a:30:b7 > fa:31:3f:ba:7b:be, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 2862: 172.16.0.227.9029 > 172.16.0.72.36726: Flags [.], seq 8192:10988, ack 1, win 9677, options [nop,nop,TS val 483833919 ecr 1703882345], length 2796
16:07:14.639328 fa:31:3f:2a:30:b7 > fa:31:3f:ba:7b:be, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1366: 172.16.0.227.9029 > 172.16.0.72.36726: Flags [P.], seq 10988:12288, ack 1, win 9677, options [nop,nop,TS val 483833919 ecr 1703882345], length 1300
16:07:14.639533 fa:31:3f:2a:30:b7 > fa:31:3f:ba:7b:be, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 4260: 172.16.0.227.9029 > 172.16.0.72.36726: Flags [.], seq 12288:16482, ack 1, win 9677, options [nop,nop,TS val 483833919 ecr 1703882346], length 4194
16:07:14.639575 fa:31:3f:2a:30:b7 > fa:31:3f:ba:7b:be, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 5658: 172.16.0.227.9029 > 172.16.0.72.36726: Flags [.], seq 16482:22074, ack 1, win 9677, options [nop,nop,TS val 483833919 ecr 1703882346], length 5592
16:07:14.639766 fa:31:3f:2a:30:b7 > fa:31:3f:ba:7b:be, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 3979: 172.16.0.227.9029 > 172.16.0.72.36726: Flags [P.], seq 22074:25987, ack 1, win 9677, options [nop,nop,TS val 483833919 ecr 1703882347], length 3913

As you see, there are many packets from 172.16.0.227 to 172.16.0.72.
I'm totally confused now. I have never created any traffic forwarding rules on the machine. But how could I explain the output of tcpdump? Is this some magic technique that allow a machine to be able to monitor the traffic between two other machines?

Does the MAC address belong to the machine? Is the machine a VM host?

@u1686_grawity  No, none of the MAC addresses belongs to the machine. Both of them belong to the two machines 172.16.0.227 and 172.16.0.72.

@u1686_grawity The machine is kind of VM host, managed with OpenStack. In fact I'm using a cloud product, which allows me to create or delete machines virtually.

I mean, is the machine a physical server that hosts other VMs or is it a VM by itself?

@u1686_grawity The three machines are all VM themselves.

@u1686_grawity  I can't see any physical server. I just bought 120 cores and 240 CPUs on the interface of the cloud product, just like AWS cloud. Then, I created three VM hosts.

@Yves - The IP addresses are internal to your network.
